# Power BI service connect mysql without gateway

Tags: powerbi

I have power bi desktop installed and up and running. Want to publish data to power bi service.
While having connection of power bi with desktop version, On publish to service, i need to open gateway to refresh the data. As i have no local source, only data i am using is remote MySQL. So why do i need gateway to have refresh the data meanwhile i am using external data-source. And then what is need of credentials of my external sources.

Is there any way to remove this gateway need and have it without it (through direct connect) ?

Comment: Can you please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hi MySQL direct connection is not available for power bi, The only direct connection support sources are Azure SQL DB, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Azure Analysis Services and Spark on Azure HDInsight.

[More Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources)